# use datagridview dev express in c#

Tags: c#, datagridview, devexpress

I want to make Food invoice for restaurant which recipient can add to grid view first and when it will be finish he can send it (with loop)with a button to data base to store there(SQL server) when I said grid view on top for store information because I done it before in data grid view for Microsoft tools it can be something else and I Cant find it in dev express tools and my project is in windows form plication

Comment: Are you saying that the control doesn't appear in the Visual Studio toolbox while you're in design mode? Have you tried the toolbox repair tool? What version of the DevExpress WinForms suite are you using? What version of Visual Studio are you using? What .NET Framework does your project target?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have this item, I suggest you re-run our installer in Repair mode. Please refer to the [How to resolve issues with Toolbox items](https://supportcenter.devexpress.com/ticket/details/ka18574#) article for more solutions regarding issues with Toolbox.

To get using the grid control follow the below documentation:

[Get Started With Data Grid and Views](https://docs.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/113894/controls-and-libraries/data-grid/getting-started-with-data-grid-and-views)